# Proximity to a new "reward" level reporting?

Tags: discussion, badges, profile-page, statistics

In follow-up to the recent [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/review-early-review-often), is there a way to determine how close you are to a given badge, such as <kbd>*Strunk & White*</kbd>, <kbd>*Archaeologist*</kbd>, or <kbd>*Sportsmanship*</kbd>?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a progress tracker on the right sidebar of the /review page:

[image: screenshot]

Once you get [Strunk & White], it will switch to showing your progress towards [Copy Editor] and [Electorate].

Comment: is it *only* for that badge?

Comment: @warren I believe it's for all badges currently relevant to reviewing. As the blog post explains, it covers Strunk & White, Civic Duty, Copy Editor, and Electorate.

Comment: I did see that in the post for the review-related badges ... still wondering if there's a way to know how close to another badge you are (eg Archaeologist or Sportsmanship)

Comment: @warren There are some queries for Data Explorer that can give you a rough idea for some badges, but badges like Sportsmanship that require checking votes (which aren't included in the data for DE) can only have wildly-inaccurate and useless queries.  Unless the devs implement more progress trackers that's the best you can do, though.